# Exception in callback: Failed to activate observer for behaviour "nomad"

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, target, vuforia

i am trying to great vuforia model target, but i got this error when i setup more one target in the same scene.

The error:

```
Exception in callback: Failed to activate observer for behaviour 'nomad_creo'
UnityEngine.Debug:LogErrorFormat (string,object[])
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.UnityLogger:LogError (string,object[])
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.Log:Error (string,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling (System.Action)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:OnStart ()
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Start (System.Action)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Start ()
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:VuforiaInitialized (Vuforia.VuforiaInitError)
System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke (object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError> (System.Action`1<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError>,Vuforia.VuforiaInitError)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:add_OnAfterVuforiaInitializedPublic (System.Action`1<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError>)
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:Awake ()
```

Someone can help me?

Thank you

The model target that is giving me this error I have tried by separately in a scene that alone and has not given me this error.  Sorry for my English that is not very good, but I hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the issue..
When two GameObjects having Image Target Behaviour component with same Image Target are active at the same time in the scene..
Vuforia throws this error in run time.

And Yes, I have this scenario in my project but I have made sure that at a time only one of those Image Targets is active in the scene.
I have set this in the OnTargetFound and OnTargetLost events.
If I have tracked an image target and suddenly shift the camera to other Image Target vuforia tracking system takes time to run the events or due to any short delay this error pops up.

Please Correct me if I am going in wrong direction.